# Laravel project in subdirectory of wordpress project

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu-20.04

Hi I am having a problem with my project, on my domain ([www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)) I have my wordpress project and in the sub folder ([www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app)) I have my laravel project, now I have tried to configure in different ways the .htaccess file but it always returns 404 error and it is as if it did not find the css, js files and all the routes

Wordpress ([www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)) .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Laravel ([www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app)) .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/public/
    RewriteRule (.*) /app/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Laravel public ([www.example.com/app/public](http://www.example.com/app/public)) (THIS WORK) .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I would advise you to use a symlink rather than putting the application in the folder. this way you can point the symlink to the public folder and the application core files will not be in a public folder (security risk)

Comment: @GertB. How should i do?

Comment: You put the laravel app outside of your public html folder, and create a symlink with `ln -s source_file symbolic_link` where source_file should be the public dir from laravel and symbolic_link the "folder" app (make sure that it does not exist yet) Search online for "create symlink".

Comment: @GertB. Yes ok, but anyway I don't see how after I can remove public from the url